# z-index is overlap css 3d transform position in FireFox

Tags: css, firefox, css-transforms

I create some 3d demo: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20810772/model/field.html
webkit render it fine.
But in FireFox 19/ FF nightly z-index overlap 3d-transform position of elements.
If element appear later in dom it overlap element that appear earlier in the dom.

Is there any way to fix it?

With all best regards.

Comment: I have checked your URL,there is a issue with z-index.
to maintain the stack order z-index is used. in dom element appear later have higher z-index as compare to element that appear earlier in the dom.

Answer (score -1):

Don't put preserve-3d and perspective on the same element.  Put preserve-3d on the outer container of your 3d scene, and perspective should go on anything *within* that scene.

Comment: Yep, so? How it may help with FF fug?

Comment: did you try it? does it fix the problem? where elements appear in the DOM and z-index, do not matter in 3D - you now need to worry about the z-axis.  However, your 3D stage is not set up properly which is showing irregular results across browers.